# X509TrustManager alert GooglePlay

Tags: android, google-play, x509certificate, trustmanager

Ok so I just received alerts for all of my regarding unsafe use of this TrustManger. The problem is I don't even know what that is, in fact it's the first time I hear about it. Anyone knows what is this? Anyone solved this issue?
I am suspecting it's in some of Ad Network Jars since I never really messed with those things, I am using FAN, AdMob and MobileCore.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is produced by the MobileCore SDK. 
Two ways of fixing the problem:

- Remove MC SDK from the app
- Wait for MC to publish a new version fixing the issue with the Trust Manager.